# Excircles of a right triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

> Given a $\triangle ABC$ such that the $A$ excircle has a radius $r_A$ and the $B$ excircle has a radius $r_B$. Prove that if $r_A + r_B = AB$ then $\triangle ABC$ is a right triangle.

I called $D$ the point where the $A$ excircle touches the side $BC$, $E$ the point where the $B$ excircle touches the side $AC$ and $F$ the point where the $C$ excircle touches the side $AB$.

Then I noticed that $AE = BD$ and that in order to prove the given statement I need to show that $BF = r_B$ and $AF = r_A$ but I don't know how to use these facts.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

In the figure, let $I$ be the in-centre, $X$ and $Y$ be the ex-centres corresponding to $A$ and $B$ respectively.

Join $XC$ and $CY$.

Note that

(i)  $\angle XCI=90^\text{o}$ and $\angle YCI=90^\text{o} \implies$ $XCY$ is a straight line

(ii)  $\angle YAX=\angle YBX = 90^\text{o} \implies ABXY$ is a cyclic quadrilateral and  $XY$ is the diameter of circle $ABXY$

(iii) In $\Delta ABX$, $\angle AXB=180^\text{o}-90^\text{o}-\frac{B}{2}-\frac{A}{2}=\frac{C}{2}$

(iv) By Sine Rule, $\frac{AB}{\sin \angle AXB}=2R=XY \implies $ $AB=XY \cdot \sin \frac {C}{2}$

(v)  From the construction, $YE=r_B$ and $EF=XG=r_A$

(vi) Hence $YF=r_A+r_B$

(vii)Given that $r_A+r_B=AB \implies$ $YF=AB$

(viii)Together with $YF=XY \cdot \sin \angle YXF$ and $AB=XY \cdot \sin \frac {C}{2}$, we have $\angle YXF=\frac {C}{2}$

(ix) Note that $BC // XF \implies $ $\angle BCX =\frac {C}{2}$

(x) Since $CI$ is the angle bisector of $\angle ACB$, $\angle ICB=\frac {C}{2}$

(xi) Hence $\angle ICX=\frac {C}{2}+\frac {C}{2}=C$

(xii)Since $\angle ICX=90^\text{o}$, therefore $C=90^\text{o}$

Answer (score 3):

The formula for the ex-radius is

$ r_A = \dfrac{ \Delta } {s - a} $

$ r_B = \dfrac{ \Delta }{ s- b} $

where $ \Delta $ is the area of the triangle, and $s = \frac{1}{2}(a + b + c) $

Given in the problem

$ r_A + r_B = AB = c $

Therefore,

$ \Delta \left( \dfrac{1}{s-a} + \dfrac{1}{s - b} \right) = c $

so that

$ \Delta ( 2 s - a - b ) = c (s - a)(s - b) $

But $2 s - a - b = c $, therefore

$ \Delta = (s - a)(s - b) $

From Heron's formula for the area,

$ \Delta = \sqrt{ s (s - a) (s - b)(s - c) }$

Therefore

$ s (s - a)(s - b) (s - c) = (s - a)^2 (s - b)^2 $

so that

$ s (s - c) = (s - a)(s - b) $

Expanding

$ s^2 - s c = s^2 - s (a + b) + a b $

Hence,

$ s (a + b - c) = a b $

But, $ s = \dfrac{1}{2}(a + b + c ) $

Therefore,

$ (a + b + c) (a + b - c) = 2 a b $

so that

$(a + b)^2 - c^2 = 2 a b $

And, from this,

$ a^2 + 2 a b + b^2 - c^2 = 2 a b $

Therefore,

$ c^2 = a^2 + b^2 $

Hence, $\triangle ABC $ is a right triangle at $C$.